# How can I convert a string representation of HEX into a byte for sending over serial in VB?

Tags: vb.net

For homework I need to send 4 bytes to the device over a serial connection. My app has 4 text boxes for inputting the hexadecimal byte that needs to be sent. I want to be able to enter something like this:

```
0x01
0x81
0x82
0x81
```

into the 4 boxes.  How do I take the string and convert it to a byte that can be sent over serial? I already sort of have it sending... something, but it's not:

```
byte(1) = Convert.toByte(textbox1)
```

Perhaps I'm inputting the hex into my text box incorrectly?

MSDN says for `Convert.toByte(string value)`

```
Parameters
value
Type: System.String
A string that contains the number to convert.
```

Thanks!

Comment: In the future, please do your best with your grammar and spelling! It takes time to edit these questions into readable condition.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you convert Byte Array to Hexadecimal String, and vice versa?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/311165/how-do-you-convert-byte-array-to-hexadecimal-string-and-vice-versa)